# OpenGL rotate around a spot

Tags: opengl, rotation

I want to rotate a `gluSphere` around a fixed point in a circular motion, like a planet going around the sun.

Would it be best to use glRotatef or glTranslate? If so, in which order should I call them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do a little of both:

- Make sure the `gluSphere` is "facing" the fixed point, so that translating forward with respect to the sphere puts you closer to the center of its orbit
- `glTranslatef` the `gluSphere` forward to the point around which you want it to rotate
- `glRotatef` the direction you want the sphere to orbit
- `glTranslatef` backwards just as far as you went forward

That way, your sphere stays the same distance from the center, but gets translated "around" in a nice orbit.

Answer (score 2):

Translate away from the center and then rotate all the way

Answer (score -2):

glRotatef will multiply the current matrix by a rotation matrix. This can (given the right vector) do what you are attempting.

glTranslatef will multiply the current matrix by a translation matrix, which would effectively "move" the object, not rotate it, so it will not be what you want.

Comment: So for a circular motion what glRotatef should I use to rotate around a set point?

Comment: I think it's true to say that he needs one of each - translate the object away from the origin, and then rotate about the origin. (where 'origin' is the center that you want to rotate around)